# Views disappears after a time from Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

Hi in my project i am using an custom adapter. When the activity which contains listview opened, image views and text views appears at first and after a time views dissappears.I couldnt find a solution do u have any idea?
edit:
Also it works on emulator but dont work on normal device?

The class where i set adapter:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_person_deatil);
    Intent detailIntent = getIntent();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String obj = detailIntent.getStringExtra("obj");
    PeopleListItem people = gson.fromJson(obj, PeopleListItem.class);

    ListView lw = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.perdetLw);

    PeopleListItem[] list = new PeopleListItem[6];
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
            list[i] = people;
        }

    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ab.setTitle(people.getName());
    ab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_person);

    PeopleDetailArrayAdapter adp = new PeopleDetailArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.person_detail_item, list);
    lw.setAdapter(adp);

}
```

The class of custom Adapter:

```
  public class PeopleDetailArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PeopleListItem> {

int resource;
Context context;
int count = 0;
public PeopleDetailArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        PeopleListItem[] list) {
    super(context, resource, list);
    this.resource = resource; 
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final PeopleListItem peopleObj = getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View listViewItem = layoutInflator.inflate(resource, null);

    final TextView textView = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.detailTw);
    final TextView textView1 = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.detailTw1);
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.detailIw);//img view kişinin resmine göre değişmeli
    final ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.detailIw1);

    switch (count) {
    case 0:
        textView.setText("Title:");
        String title = peopleObj.getTitle();
        textView1.setText(title);
        break;
    case 1:
        textView.setText("Department:");
        String dep = peopleObj.getDepart();
        textView1.setText(dep);
        break;  
    case 2:
        textView.setText("Work Phone:");
        String wp = peopleObj.getWorkPhone();
        textView1.setText(wp);
        imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case 3:
        textView.setText("Mobile Phone:");
        String mp = peopleObj.getMobilePhone();
        textView1.setText(mp);
        imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        imageView1.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case 4:
        textView.setText("Email:");
        String email = peopleObj.getEmail();
        textView1.setText(email);
        break;
    case 5:
        textView.setText("Manager:");
        String man = peopleObj.getManager();
        textView1.setText(man);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    count++;
    return listViewItem;
}

}
```

Comment: why do you assign all elements of `list` to the same `people` variable?

Comment: not to lose time for creating layout i create a simple layout for a row which include all i need.

Comment: you can use **ViewHolder** pattern for better performance.

Comment: @calypso with your code, your listview is supposed to be like: row 1 - only title, row 2 - only department, row 3 - only work phone, etc. Pretty strange design for a listview, frankly

Comment: @mangusta yeah u are right as i said in question i see these for a sec then disappears.

Comment: @mangusta i just be lazy in order not to create a complex layout dude and find this solution.

Comment: @calypso I think you should declare `PeopleListItem[] list` in your adapter, then add `this.list = list;` to constructor and replace `final PeopleListItem peopleObj = getItem(position);` with `final PeopleListItem peopleObj = list[position];` .see my reply below

Comment: @mangusta i tried but unfortunately not worked menn

Comment: @mangusta do u have any idea about firstly appearing and then disappearing?

Comment: @calypso does your app terminate ? did you check your logcat ?

Comment: @calypso try removing `default:` clause from your `switch`

Comment: @mangusta i removed default but doesnt work again

Comment: @mangusta no it does not terminate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved problem by using `position` instead of using `count`

```
          public class PeopleDetailArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PeopleListItem> {

int resource;
Context context;

public PeopleDetailArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        PeopleListItem[] list) {
    super(context, resource, list);
    this.resource = resource; 
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final PeopleListItem peopleObj = getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View listViewItem = layoutInflator.inflate(resource, null);

    final TextView textView = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.detailTw);
    final TextView textView1 = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.detailTw1);

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        textView.setText("Title");
        String title = peopleObj.getTitle();
        textView1.setText(title);
        break;
    case 1:
        textView.setText("Department");
        String dep = peopleObj.getDepart();
        textView1.setText(dep);
        break;  
    case 2:
        textView.setText("Work");
        String wp = peopleObj.getWorkPhone();
        textView1.setText(wp);
        break;
    case 3:
        textView.setText("Mobile");
        String mp = peopleObj.getMobilePhone();
        textView1.setText(mp);
        break;
    case 4:
        textView.setText("Email");
        String email = peopleObj.getEmail();
        textView1.setText(email);
        break;
    case 5:
        textView.setText("Manager");
        String man = peopleObj.getManager();
        textView1.setText(man);
        break;
    }

    return listViewItem;
}
```

}